# Custom page image from an image file

Tags: c++, xcode, wxwidgets

I am learning about treebook in wxwidgets and I want to customize the icon that will appear in my page control. I look at the sample and they use images from the wxArtProvider, which seemingly only provides some icons. I want to use my own file as the icon (png file), but I can not find a material to do that.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
    m_chkShowImages = true;
    m_panel    = NULL;
    m_bookCtrl = NULL;
    


    const wxSize imageSize(32,32);
    wxBitmap icontest = wxBitmap("add_clicked.png", wxBITMAP_TYPE_ANY);
    m_images.push_back(icontest);
    m_images.push_back(wxArtProvider::GetIcon(wxART_QUESTION, wxART_OTHER, imageSize));
    m_images.push_back(wxArtProvider::GetIcon(wxART_WARNING, wxART_OTHER, imageSize));
    m_images.push_back(wxArtProvider::GetIcon(wxART_ERROR, wxART_OTHER, imageSize));
```

Are there any ways that I can change those icons with my own files? Feel free to ask for more information if there is some where I make you confused. Thank you so much and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any `wxBitmap` created in any way you want with this (or any other similar) control(s), the sample only uses some standard icons for simplicity. And a `wxBitmap` can be loaded from a disk file, created from image data embedded into your program (see `wxBITMAP_PNG`) or even created dynamically during run-time by using `wxMemoryDC`.

Comment: I have considered the idea of using wxBitmap like in the code I posted in the question. However, there may be something wrong with my implementation that it did not work. Do you mind giving me some examples of how I can customize the icon with an image file? Thank you so much.

Comment: Just using `wxBitmap("path/to/the/image.png")` should work. For other file types, ensure that `wxInitAllImageHandlers()` was called.

Comment: I tried changing the thing inside m_images.push_back and I got some errors like this:

/Users/nguyenbachtruonggiang/Downloads/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/src/osx/core/bitmap.cpp(1407): assert ""IsOk()"" failed in GetWidth(): invalid bitmap
Collecting stack trace information, please wait.../Users/nguyenbachtruonggiang/Downloads/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/src/osx/core/bitmap.cpp(1426): assert ""IsOk()"" failed in GetScaleFactor(): invalid bitmap

Comment: Do you mind suggesting me some ways to fix it, I am very new to this topic so I don't really know how to sort it out

Comment: I replaced it like this:

 ::wxInitAllImageHandlers();
 m_images.push_back(wxBITMAP_PNG("add_clicked.png"));

Comment: I just tried another method and I figured out it was because the size of my image is different from the size I set for icon from art provider. Thank you so much for helping me out.